# Pointer points to NULL in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

So I have this class which holds some of my objects after they are generated. I will walk you through them:

dungeon is a pointer to an object of the Dungeon Class which holds some DungeonLayers in a vector named dungeonLayers which then holds a vector of Chambers name (dungeon is filled)

When I run this code:

```
Game::Game(std::vector<Enemy>* e, Dungeon* d, Hero* h) {
    enemies = e;
    dungeon = d;
    hero = h;
    DungeonLayer *currentLayer = dungeon->dungeonLayers.at(0);
    Chamber *currentChamber = currentLayer->chambers.at(0);
};
```

currentLayer and currentChamber both point to NULL but the dungeonLayers.at(0) is filled with a DungeonLayer in 'dungeon' when I look in the locals at the breakpoint I put there. Why does my currentLayer point to NULL?

I am new to C++ so that's why I ask this question, I might do something really obviously wrong here.

Comment: And you set the breakpoint after the assignment I'm hoping? a screenshot of what you're experiencing would be appropriate here.

Comment: Try: DungeonLayer * cl = &(dungeon->dungeonLayers[0]);

Comment: @IssamTP The code shows us that dungeonLayers already is a vector holding DungeonLayer pointers, no need to get the address of them.

Comment: "...which holds some `DungeonLayers` in a vector.." - not according to *that* code. For that code to compile without warning or error, `dungeon->dungeonLayers` holds *pointers*, not objects.

Comment: @IssamTP your answer worked! If you put it at an answer I will accept it!

Comment: @Jelmer If that worked, the code you posted can't possibly compile, much less run.

Comment: [MCVE].... c'mon, you've been here for a year already!

Comment: Just a couple of minor things, it's generally good to prefix class member variables with something like `m_`, it helps readability so much, also you should probably be using a initialization list and the semi colon after your constructor definition is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DungeonLayer *currentLayer = dungeon->dungeonLayers.at(0);
Chamber *currentChamber = currentLayer->chambers.at(0);
```

is formally incorrect, because *currentLayer is a pointer, that means:

```
currentLayer contains address of an object of type DungeonLayer
```

So you have not initialized correctly currentLayer.
Correct way to use the pointer type:

```
DungeonLayer *currentLayer = &(dungeon->dungeonLayers[0]); //address of something
```

Is this clear? Or I'll try to put in a better form.

Comment: DungeonLayer *currentLayer = &(dungeon->dungeonLayers.at(0));
 I have it like this now and that works, the code compiles too! Thanks :)